# yii handsontable can't save

Tags: php, yii, handsontable

i was want to save my data from handsontable. Nothings error when i try to save my data. but my data from handsontable cannot insert in my database.
Here is my code

```
public function actionSavePricelist($id)
{
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    if(!Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');

    $user = Yii::app()->session['loginSession']['userId'];

    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        $vendor_price= json_decode($_POST['price_list']);
        $flagError=0;
        for($i=0;$i<count($vendor_price->data);$i++) {
            $row = $vendor_price->data[$i];
            if($row[0] == null && $row[1] == null) continue;
            else { 
                if(!isset($row[3])){
                    $mVenPri = new MstVendorPricelist;
                    $idcity = MstCity::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                            'city_name' => $row[1]
                        )
                    );
                    $idc = $idcity->city_id;

                    $mVenPri->item_id=$row[3];
                    $mVenPri->vendor_id=$model->vendor_id;
                    $mVenPri->city_id=$idc;
                    $mVenPri->price=$row[2];
                    $mVenPri->created_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $mVenPri->created_by=$user;
                    $mVenPri->modified_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $mVenPri->modified_by=$user;

                    if(!$mVenPri->save())
                        $flagError++;

                } else {
                    $modelprice=MstVendorPriceList::model()->findByPk($id);
                    $idcity = MstCity::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                        'city_name' => $row[1])
                        );
                    $idc = $idcity->city_id;

                    $modelprice->item_id=$row[3];
                    $modelprice->vendor_id=$model->vendor_id;
                    $modelprice->city_id=$idc;
                    $modelprice->price=$row[2];
                    $modelprice->created_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $modelprice->created_by=$user;
                    $modelprice->modified_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $modelprice->modified_by=$user;

                    if(!$modelprice->save())
                        $flagError++;
                }                               
            }               
        } 
        if($flagError == 0)
            echo CJSON::encode(array('success'=>true,'msg'=>'You have successfully added data.'));
        else
            echo CJSON::encode(array('msg'=>'Error occurred during inserting details.'));
        // var_dump($vendor_price);
}
```

actually this function is update but,similar like save data. Update my vendor and save new data from handsontable.
please help me. is there any wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like, what before save validation in `MstVendorPricelist` model, return false. You should find out it in model code. Ensure that all fields  get a correct data, when you fill it in controller.

Also you can try disable validations when inserting data. [read this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#save()-detail)

```
 if(!$mVenPri->save(false))
        $flagError++;
```

You find more information about Active Record in this [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#inserting-updating-data)

Happy coding!